# C# Catching Exception From Invoked Delegate on another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I have some code as follows. This is running on "Thread 2"

```
WebBrowser browser = this.webBrowser    
browser.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { browser.Document.GetElementById("somebutton").InvokeMember("click"); }));
Thread.Sleep(500);
browser.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", username); }));
//folowed by several more similar statments
```

Essentially I am Invoking some methods on a WebBrowser control created on a different thread, "Thread 1".

If the element on the current page loaded in browser does not contain an element "somebtn" or "username", an exception is thrown from "Thread 1".

Is there any way to catch that exception on "Thread 2"? I know I could use try catches within the delegates and have a special delegate that returns some value(like an exception), but is there any way around that options?

Note*: I require the Thread.Sleep as the particular page requires some delay between certain events. If there was some way to combine these events into a single delegate(while retaining some form of non-blocking delay), I think that could work and I would just wrap all of them in single try catch and create a delegate that returns an exception.

Comment: If I take a look in MSDN at the `WebBrowser` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491073.aspx) I do not see any `Invoke`  method. Which one are you using?

Comment: Invoke is a method of all the UI Controls...it allows updates to the controls from other threads and such.

Comment: If your assumption is true, and you call Control.Invoke, all delegates are invoked on the UI-thread. So... on the same thread. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Control.Invoke()` executes delegate over UI thread - it is still a synchronous call. Synchronous meaning `Invoke` will not return until the delegate has completed execution (or exception thrown). You can simply catch the exceptions thrown there.

```
WebBrowser browser = this.webBrowser;
try {    
    browser.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { browser.Document.GetElementById("somebutton").InvokeMember("click"); }));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    browser.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", username); }));
} catch(Exception e) 
{
    //catch in Thread 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use WebBrowser.Invoke, all delegates are executes on the thread of the User Interface. So everything will be executed on one single thread. So in your question you want the UI thread to wait for itself? Assuming this is not what you want, I took some "freedom" in my answer:

There are multiple options, but I will show the most simple one:

- Start both delegates with BeginInvoke.
- Store the `IAsyncResult` of thread1 in a local variable.
- Thread2 will do its work.
- Thread2 will do the `EndInvoke` of thread1.

Code:

```
WebBrowser browser = this.webBrowser;
MethodInvoker thread1 = delegate
{
    browser.Document.GetElementById("somebutton").InvokeMember("click");
};
IAsyncResult result1 = thread1.BeginInvoke(null, null);
Thread.Sleep(500);
MethodInvoker thread2 = delegate
{
    browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", username);
    try
    {
        thread1.EndInvoke(result1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception of thread1.
    }
};
thread2.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```